# how to quick sort sprites in a 2d game with lua?

Tags: sorting, lua

I'm working on a 2d Game. I use lua script in all game logic. Now the problem is the sorting too slow. Can anyone help to improve it?

Here is my code about zobject list.

```
local c = class("ZList") -- class is a function to generate a "Class"

function c:insert(v) -- every v(value or object) has a z field
    if v.z == nil then v.z = -1 end
    if self.head == nil then
        self.head = {val=v, nxt=nil}
    else
        local p = self.head
        local pp = p -- pp is a pointer to pre node
        while v.z and p and p.val.z and p.val.z <= v.z do
            pp = p
            p = p.nxt
        end
        if p == self.head then
            self.head = {val=v, nxt=p}
        else
            pp.nxt = {val=v, nxt=p}
        end
    end
end

function c:delete(v)
    local p = self.head
    local pp
    while p and p.val ~= v do
        pp = p
        p = p.nxt
    end

    if p ~= nil then
        if p == self.head then
            self.head = p.nxt
        else
            pp.nxt = p.nxt
        end
    end
end
```

___  *update* __*_*__*_*

Thank you Nicol and every replied! I followed your suggestion: use table.insert and table.sort, use a static list which don't need to be sort. Here are my final codes:

```
    local remove_list
    sort(Graphics.viewports, comp)
    for _, viewport in pairs(Graphics.viewports) do
        if viewport.visible then
            remove_list = {}
            if not viewport.static then sort(viewport.sprites, comp) end
            for k, sprite in pairs(viewport.sprites) do
                if not sprite:paint() then
                    table.insert(remove_list,1, k)
                end
            end
            for _, k in pairs(remove_list) do
                table.remove(viewport.sprites, k)
            end
        end
    end
```

Comment: Could you comment your code ? I don't really have the time to go in-depth... comments or explanation would help... a lot. And p, pp ? Sorry but.. WTF is that naming... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop putting your sprites in a linked list. Put them in a regular list. Insertion time is not going to hurt you nearly as badly as the memory allocations and such for a linked list will. Just use a regular Lua list, with `table.insert` and so forth.

Alternatively, do you really *need* all of your sprites to be sorted? Most likely (depending on the circumstances of course), you can just draw them in layers: all of Layer 0 (in any order), then all of Layer 1, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the build in `table.sort`? Using that you have 2 options

1. Specify a sorting function upon invocation: `table.sort(table,comp)`, where `comp(a,b)` is a function returning true if a
2. implement a __lt metamethod for your sprite class, implementing the `<` operation.

`table.sort` aparently uses a variant of the quicksort algorithm (according to [LuaSorting](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaSorting) on the lua-users wiki).